# Execute multistatement MySql through C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm working with MySql database in C#.

I'm using MySql.Data.dll liibrary if that matters:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.2.html

I wonder, may I execute several sql statements through single C# command

I tried something like:

```
string query = @"SELECT @id_article:= MAX(id_article) FROM articles WHERE name='abc';
                 INSERT INTO prices(id_article,price)  VALUES (@id_article ,10);";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connMySQL);
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have more experience with Sql Server, something like this would work there.

Here I get syntax error. Still when I run these commands through SqlYog (a management software for MySql) they somehow worked.

Is it possible to execute such multicommand query in MySql and is it possible to do through .NET?

Comment: You may also want to verify it's not the MySql config disallowing multicommands by default. Sorry I can't back this up with a link, but I remember there are databases which require a change to the config to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You use user variables in the query. So you must add parameter to connection string:

```
Allow User Variables=true
```

Multiple SQL statements are allowed by default ("AllowBatch" parameter).

More info at: [MySQL Connector/Net Connection String Options Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)